# how can I find the type of parent for TextView?

Tags: android

please how can i apply this style for textview:
my style is :

```
<style name="styleCircle" parent="">

    <item name="textColor" >#000000</item>
    <item name="textSize" >25sp</item>
    <item name="android:background" >@drawable/azkar_shape</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">visible</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>

</style>
```

i cant find parent for this type. I am tried a lot of parents for textview but 
it gave me this error

> Error:(1858) error: style attribute 'attr/textColor (aka com.almasbaha.yazeed:attr/textColor)' not found.
>   Error:(1859) error: style attribute 'attr/textSize (aka com.almasbaha.yazeed:attr/textSize)' not found.
>   Error:(1858) style attribute 'attr/textColor (aka com.almasbaha.yazeed:attr/textColor)' not found.
>   Error:(1859) style attribute 'attr/textSize (aka com.almasbaha.yazeed:attr/textSize)' not found.

how to implements that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<style>` tags are not required to have a `parent` attribute; you can just leave it out.

The parent is used so that you don't have to copy/paste huge blocks of styling information when you want to modify only one item in the style set.

```
<style name="MyBaseStyle">
    <item name="some_attribute_1">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_2">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_3">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_4">value</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOtherStyle" parent="MyBaseStyle">
    <item name="some_attribute_5">value</item>
</style>
```

In this example, `MyOtherStyle` will behave as though I'd written this instead:

```
<style name="MyOtherStyle">
    <item name="some_attribute_1">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_2">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_3">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_4">value</item>
    <item name="some_attribute_5">value</item>
</style>
```

Also, you should probably change these two lines to use the `android` namespace:

```
<item name="android:textColor" >#000000</item>
<item name="android:textSize" >25sp</item>
```